# pumping lemma for $L=\{a^n b^m c^k \mid n = m \vee m\neq k\}$

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

Using pumping lemma, how can I prove that $L=\{a^n b^m c^k \mid n = m \vee m\neq k\}$ is not regular?.

If I choose $w= a^m b^m c^m$ and pump up with $i=2$, if have $a^m=1 b^m c^m$ but the string is still in the language. Any hint?

Comment: I tried to improve your question, but there are still parts that do not make sense for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to show that $L$ isn't regular is by noticing that
$$ L \cap b^+c^+ = \{ b^m c^k : m,k \geq 1, m \neq k \}. $$
This should look familiar.

Comment: yes i do agree but what if i want to use the pumping lemma?

Comment: Then keep working on it.

Comment: i think i got an idea; what if for a given m, we choose w=a^m b^m a^m; clearly this w is in L; and we can easily find the contradiction of the pumping lemma here